# Explicitly deleted functions

Tags: c++, mfc, ostream, deleted-functions, lpcstr

we are migrating code to VS 2019 from legacy code

We have an overloaded function on operator '<<' that is invoking basic_ostream function
when executing the following lines.

```
CStringArray asLine;
 
using ostream       = basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>;
ostream os;
    os << (LPCTSTR)asLine[nLine2]; <---- this line is producing the  C2280 error with message
"basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const wchar_t*) = delete"
```

This was working in legacy application. how to overcome this issue?

please suggest any workaround

```
CStringArray asLine; // class with set and get functions.
ostream os;
int nLine2 = 20; // nline has subscript valve to the asline[]

os << (LPCTSTR)asLine[nLine2];
```

Comment: Guessing this is MFC. Please tag your question properly to get the correct audience for it.

Comment: `basic_ostream<TCHAR>`

Comment: *"This was working in legacy application."* - Nope, it wasn't. The legacy application compiled to different code, which can still be made to work today. What changed is the compiler environment: In the legacy case the `MBCS` and `_MBCS` preprocessor symbols were defined. This changed to having the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbols defined. As far as the compiler is concerned, `TCHAR` changed from `char` to `wchar_t`.

Comment: Don't use here the cast LPCTSTR if you want a char, which is need for ostream. Or you can try to replace ostream with wostream.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. the use of wostream in place of ostream helped to solve the issue.